# How to set outline color of a textbox via angular material theming

Tags: angular, angular-material

I recently upgraded my angular app from v14 -> v16, after that i also updated @angular/material to most recent version which required a shift to mcd based components.

Currently i have lots of input fields with appearance="outline". Before the upgrade outline color was "light gray" and currently for two days in a row i am attemting to change the color of outline to something else then black without any progress.

[image]

I am attempting to go the way of theming and palleting which is descirbed [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#create-your-own-palette) but without any luck. Even if i set all the hue and contrast to red color outline is still black.

I figured out that there is a custom property with name "--mdc-outlined-text-field-outline-color" which sets the actual color, because if i disable it i can set the color of the outline without problems.

Here is my setup:

```
    $mat-dark: (
    50: #FF0000,
    100: #FF0000,
    200: #FF0000,
    300: #FF0000,
    400: #FF0000,
    500: #FF0000,
    600: #FF0000,
    700: #FF0000,
    800: #FF0000,
    900: #FF0000,
    A100: #FF0000,
    A200: #FF0000,
    A400: #FF0000,
    A700: #FF0000,
    contrast: (
        50: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        100: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        200: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        300: yellow,
        400: yellow,
        500: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        600: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        700: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        800: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        900: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        A100: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        A200: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        A400: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
        A700: rgba(yellow, 0.87),
    )
);
// Define the Material palettes
$primary: mat.define-palette($mat-dark);
$accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-blue-palette, 600, 400, 700);
$warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);
$typography: mat.define-typography-config(
    $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 1.125, 400)
);
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $primary,
   accent: $accent,
   warn: $warn
 ),
 density: 0,
));
@include mat.core();
@include mat.all-component-typographies($typography);
@include mat.core-theme($theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

What am i doing wrong?